# windows 10 word doc says already existing file do I want to relpace it?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am told that I have an existing file and if I want to replace it with the new one.I know that this has been asked before but my situation has a different twist. Please be patient with me
as I attempt to explain.

OS is windows 10

I had been writing a poem. I had to stop so I tapped the X tab which then brought up the window asking what I wanted to do with it? I clicked save as. The title to the poem was in the file box, I clicked the save box next to it and the window closed.I closed another window in word doing the same procedure and shut off the computer.

when I went back to word to continue writing, the existing file window popped up. why this window popped up i can't answer, There were no others. So with that understanding I clicked yes since their telling me I have two exact files..shouldn't be a problem right?

Well I discovered wrong, my poem is nowhere to be found and the only thing they took and replaced was it's title. It appears they made a duplicate of another poem I was writing. now I have to different titles for the same poem and the titles do not resemble each other. What happened to my original piece of work?

I tried a system restore, but that made it go back three days so not even the replaced one was there. I've attempted to create the restore point back 1 day but it doesn't show up as one they will use. so I could only restore it back to the time of the change.

I hope someone can make sense out of what I'm trying to explain and even better know a way I can get my work back. the version of word is 2016.

Thank you

Joy

Comment: First, you should always be doing nightly backups (at minimum) if you have work that is important. As for the file, check your temp folder for your user name, a lot of programs write their intermediate temporary files there, though I don't know if word does. You can also try a file recovery program to scan your computer and recover the file... but if you overwrote it, the file is probably gone.

Answer (score 0):

"Please be patient" with this answer.(ha ha !)
So many ways to do the same thing.
I've spent half a lifetime as a qualified Electronics Technician,
chasing problems in Windows, Grrrrrrrrr . . . !!!

Well you DID ask, so here goes:
Look in the re-cycle bin, or enter poems name/s into the Cortana Search window, select Documents from the icons near the bottom, hover over any results to see location, or right click result then accept "Open File Location" and it will take you to the file ,using the computers Filing System,
(called File Explorer, little Yellow Folder on Taskbar at bottom, formerly Windows Explorer),

but it sounds like you may have lost the first file by accepting "Replace".

(One surefire way to interrupt the creative process is to get a Windows computer involved, better to use a £50 digital voice recorder, or some other reliable hardware, like a pen, and poss a camera to upload a picture of your text, there is even software in most printer/scanners called OCR, Optical Character Recognition, that scans a single picture of your poem,then turns it into separate letters,as in a Word document,but that's going back into the computer)

Also you could attempt to locate the poem/s that you HAVE got,right click it,then at the bottom click on properties.
This window will contain the location of the poem's file, ie its PATH & location.
It will look similar to

C:\Users\YourLocalAccountName\blah\blah\Documents

Copy and paste this path into Cortana Search OR Find your way there with the File Explorer,and see if your missing file is in the same place,but to repeat, I think you may have destroyed it.

OR Open Word,on right hand side, select RECENT
This MAY be your best bet.

Also try Cortana Search  with "autosave" in the filename.
Try "autosave"  or "autosave.docx"  or "*autosave"  or "*autosave.docx"

or best 2    "autosave.* "     or     "PoemName.* "

(NB Never enter the "", that's just me using them for clarity)

One thing just occured to me ,you said you used SaveAs, I wonder what filetype you agreed to saveAs, it could have been any of 17 file formats
in the SaveAs window.
So just in case you selected other than Word Document (.docx)

Enter in Cortana Search Window

```
OriginalPoemName.*
```

or  autosave.*

This searches for those names of ALL File formats.
Don't enter asterisk.asterisk
That will list EVERY file in your computer!  >1000's

Or use Cortana Search, enter *.docx , select Documents from the icons near the bottom. 
Here you've asked to search for ALL files of that type,it would contain your poem, if it's not gone forever.

If that was the case, and you HAD to have it, only a forensic engineer could recover it from your hard disc drive,files are not actually deleted,just marked for overwriting.
If already overwritten,the only way to recover the file is ,I believe,
using an expensive technique involving an Electron Microscope looking for magnetic echoes on the magnetic hard disc.

One other possibility is Windows 10 is malfunctioning as per normal.
I've just RUINED my lovely Sony Laptop by "Upgrading" to Win 10,
so i've ditched Microsoft  finally and forever in disgust,
now communicating here with a Google Chromebook.
It starts in 3 seconds,shuts down in 2, CANNOT get a virus,
Only cost £170,and uses about one hundredth of data allowance.
It's everything you want from a computer,(unless you want to do programming / writing code,apps for Windows etc.)
Good Luck,
feel free to ask for more help,
Clive,London.

Comment: Well Clive from UK, London

Comment: Joy, seem to have lost majority of your comment ? or poss not ?   ps you have posted a face pic and a surname. The net is awash with people trawling social media sites and any sites with user profiles, looking for targets for identity theft and worse. Clivey.

Comment: Joy. . . .ps, u should have used SAVE,  not SaveAs !